# How to get a table name from a column value in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have indexed a series of tables in a column named `title` in a custom made `index_table`. I want to select a particular table using the column value from `index_table`.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT title FROM index_table WHERE rowid = 1);
```

This line `SELECT title FROM index_table WHERE rowid = 1` contains the name of the table from which I want to `SELECT *`.

However this code does not work. It returns only the selected column value from the `index_table`.

How can I select table from a value in a column?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you're trying to do in any RDMS that I'm familiar with. Neither column, nor table names can be set via variables or subqueries. You have two ways to handle this:

1. Use two steps in your application logic. One to get the table name, the second builds the query and executes it.
2. Use some join trickery. It's hard to build a query for you without the schema available, but something like what I have below should do the equivalent.

```sql
select
    title_table.*
from
    title_table
    join index_table
        on title_table.id = index_table.id
where
    index_table.rowid = 1
```